# onclick event interferes with native submit form action

Tags: jquery, submit, onclicklistener

I have been beating my brains on this. I have an onclick event associated with a form submit button. If I remove the onclick event and use native submit, it works. I then put the onclick back in and added the submit(). The form submits but the php script fails. Unfortunately I need the on(click) in order for more other scripts to work as the will not work with standard javascript onclick. here is example of my code any tips are appreciated.

```
<form id="target" action="deliorder.php" method="post" onSubmit="rmvspaces()">
<input type="hidden" name="Subject" id="Subject" value="Deli Order">
<input type="text" name="TotalOrder" id="TotalOrder" >
<textarea name="Details" id="Details"  autocomplete="off"></textarea>
<div class="inpcont">
Name <input name="Name" id="Name"  class="entry" type="text"></div> 
<div class="inpcont">
Email <input name="Email" id="Email"  class="entry" type="text"></div>
<div class="inpcont">
Phone <input name="Phone" id="Phone"  class="entry" type="text"></div>
<div class="inpcont">
Zip <input name="Zip" id="Zip"  class="entry" type="text"></div>
<input name="Submit" id="Submit" class="btn" type="submit"  value="SUBMIT" style="margin-left:255px; margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:10px;">
</form>

</div>

</div>
</div>

<script>//Add new item button

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#itmid').click(function() {
        addItem($('#itmid').val());
    });
});

$(".btn").on("click",function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var content = $('#order').html();
$("#ordertxt").html(content);
upAmt();
duporder();
totorder();
rmvit();
copyorder();
$( "#target" ).submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Try adding `return false` in your form onSubmit attribute.

Comment: remove `onSubmit="rmvspaces()"` add the function to your `.btn` click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browsers behavior is once the button click event is fired, it will execute the event handler if there is any for the button after that call will be passed to the parent element..If there is any handler written for the parent that will get executed..
Basically when you are clicking a button, internally you are also clicking the parent element..This is what the behavior inside..Hope this will be useful info

If you use event.stopPropagation(), then call will not be passed to the parent.

For IE: window.event.cancelBubble = true

Comment: Tiger that did it. I replaced event.preventDefault(); with event.stopPropagation() and added window.event.cancelBubble = true. Interestingly I'm get a double submit with explorer on windows. This may be my php script. do you think removing event.preventDefault(); could cause this? Works fine on a mac safari. I will do some more testing tonight.

Comment: Just a note about the double submit issue: I also removed $("#target").submit(); to use the native submit action, so this is not causing the problem.